# Flutter returns Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug' as soon as I add packages

Tags: android, flutter, dart, build.gradle, dart-packages

I want to make an Android app with Flutter that uses the firebase ml kit to perform text recognition on images. I have successfully added firebase to my flutter project, but as soon as I add the packages `image_picker: 0.6.1+4` and `firebase_ml_vision: 0.9.2+1` I get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Users\mathi\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\firebase-analytics-impl-11.4.2.aar\266afe38e9d564b66b359ca5823523b4\jars\classes.ja
```

The error also occures when I add only one of the two packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update build.gradle to com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0 and do flutter run -v in your build in editor terminal. Because maybe you have to update your gradle-wrapper.properties too in your android folder.